# Unindex maven repository https://repo.grails.org/grails/core in Intellij with Grails 3.0

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, grails-3.0, intellij-15

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 and I am trying to create a Grails 3.0 application and ran into issues.

While trying to create a Grails 3.0 project I get the following.

[image]

After doing what it does I also noticed that the Grails Tool Window is on the upper left is gone.  When I open the repositories list and click on update I get the following error:

[image]

I have seen some other questions that it says to click on 'Disable....' but i do not think so...

1. Will not i need the grails core repo at some poing during development?
2. How come the Grails Tool Window disappeared? How to make it come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem i changed (the file is build.gradle)
"https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/"
for 
"http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"

So close and open your project again.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you are using gradle for all of your projects, you can remove maven from your development machine entirely.  then, add 'apply plugin: "maven" ' to your build.gradle files.  then, you can completely ignore your IDE's messages about Unindexed remote maven repositories.  gradle will take care of it for you.